# Why is my svg not appearing?

Tags: html, css, svg

I saved an .svg from Photoshop with the dimensions I want it to appear as by default. It appeared fine on the page using the following markup, but was blurry.

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="~/Assets/images/premium-feature-star.svg" class="premiumFeatureButton"></object>
```

So, I re-saved the .svg in larger dimensions from Photoshop (overwriting the existing image), and I tried setting the viewBox attribute in the .svg to the dimensions I want the image to appear as, (see the code below). Now I don't see the image appear on my web page.  Here's the .svg code:

(I've tried removing the image width and height from the svg code below)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 21 21">
  <image id="Layer_0" data-name="Layer 0" x="5" y="5" width="385" height="385" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/>
</svg>
```

When I look at my webpage, I see that the .svg is still scaled to it's original dimensions:

[image]

Here's the css (which was displaying the old .svg correctly):

```
.premiumFeatureButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 408px;
    left: 380px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

The element is contained within a div. I've tried setting height and width of the containing div as percentages.

Here's the div that the .svg is contained in:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a higher z-index or adding the CSS content property? content: " ";

Comment: The css is the same as it was when the original (smaller) image I used was appearing. I tried adding the content property to the svg css. Why do you think that could have fixed it? It's not the z-index that's the issue

Comment: Could you re-create a version of this in a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Thanks Steve - now solved. Please see my answer below

Answer (score 6):

I needed to set height and width on the svg *and* the image contained inside the svg, to the desired pixel dimensions. I also set the svg viewBox attribute (which specifies that the visible area of the svg should be from the top left corner (0 0) to the bottom right corner (21 21) of the svg:)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="21" height="21" viewBox="0 0 21 21">
  <image id="Layer_0" data-name="Layer 0" width="21" height="21"
```

Comment: Yes, that was my problem as well. Searched forever for it, thanks!